# Wait for a process to complete in CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I want to write a batch file that executes another batch file, waits for it to complete the process (i.e. wait till the CMD window closes), then starts another application (.exe). How can I do that? I've tried this but it runs both processes simultaneously:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\batch1.bat" /w
start "" "C:\Program Files\process1.exe"
```

P.S: I'm not sure if it matters, but the batch1.bat file that I mentioned executes a group of programs which takes a few seconds to complete.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your basic error is the positioning of `/w` in the start command: in your command it is a parameter to `batch1`, not to `start`. You should use:

```
start /w "" "C:\Program Files\batch1.bat"
```

However, it is more efficient not to start a new `cmd` process and instead use:

```
call "C:\Program Files\batch1.bat"
```

Comment: using start ended up not working for the flow i was using.  the "call" command worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate on why `call` works better?  I never knew about this until just now